# move_upload_file with multiple pictures

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is what I originally had...

```
$('#file').change(function(){
  var file = this.files[0];
  var name = file.name;
  var size = file.size;
  var type = file.type;
  if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(name)) {              
    alert('You must select an image file only');              
  }
  if (size > 5000000) {
    alert('File size must be less than 5 Megabytes');  
  }
  if (size <= 0) {
    alert('File size must be larger than 0');  
  }
});
```

and then later towards the AJAX part I had...

```
  var file_data = $('#file').prop('files')[0];  
  var form_data = new FormData();
```

and in my php file I had...

```
if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    }
    else {
$filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];   //this param contains name of file
$arr = explode('.', $filename);
$extension=end($arr);
$newfilename=$first_name . '_' . $last_name . '_' . date('m-j-y_h-i-s') . '.' . $extension;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' .$newfilename);
}
```

**This worked perfectly, not I want to actually go ahead and add 2 more files to be uploaded. I'm just not sure how to go about fixing it up.**

This is what I did so far, but I'm 100% sure it isn't correct

```
$('#fileFace').change(function(){
  var file = this.files[0];
  var name = file.name;
  var size = file.size;
  var type = file.type;
  if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(name)) {              
    alert('You must select an image file only');              
  }
  if (size > 5000000) {
    alert('File size must be less than 5 Megabytes');  
  }
  if (size <= 0) {
    alert('File size must be larger than 0');  
  }
});
$('#fileFront').change(function(){
  var file = this.files[0];
  var name = file.name;
  var size = file.size;
  var type = file.type;
  if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(name)) {              
    alert('You must select an image file only');              
  }
  if (size > 5000000) {
    alert('File size must be less than 5 Megabytes');  
  }
  if (size <= 0) {
    alert('File size must be larger than 0');  
  }
});

$('#fileBack').change(function(){
  var file = this.files[0];
  var name = file.name;
  var size = file.size;
  var type = file.type;
  if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(name)) {              
    alert('You must select an image file only');              
  }
  if (size > 5000000) {
    alert('File size must be less than 5 Megabytes');  
  }
  if (size <= 0) {
    alert('File size must be larger than 0');  
  }
});
```

**I'm not sure how to go about editing the AJAX part as well as the PHP part to add 2 additional files.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of using a class to re-use the same javascript for multiple input elements:

html:

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>

      <input type="file" class="file" name="file1"><br/>
      <input type="file" class="file" name="file2"><br/>
      <input type="file" class="file" name="file3"><br/>

      <button class='sub'>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

javascript:

```
$(function(){

  $('.file').change(function(){
    var file = this.files[0];
    var name = file.name;
    var size = file.size;
    var type = file.type;
    if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(name)) {              
      alert('You must select an image file only');              
    }
    if (size > 5000000) {
      alert('File size must be less than 5 Megabytes');  
    }
    if (size <= 0) {
      alert('File size must be larger than 0');  
    }

    console.log(file, name);

  });


  $('.sub').click(function() {

    $('.file').each(function(index, el) {
      console.log('Input ' + el);
    });

  });

});
```

See it working in plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Bt2pE26VYtY4bmWIUaXc?p=preview